# Native sql query- SQL Injection Attack

Tags: java, security, jpa

I'm working with JPA. How could my application be SQL injection safe if I'm using a native sql query (not entity query)? I need to build the native sql query with the data submitted by a user from a html form.

If I use parameters in the native sql I can avoid SQL injection attacks, but my problem is that I can't be sure how many data fields are being submitted by the user.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should use positional parameters binding:

```
String queryString = "select * from EMP e where e.name = ?1";
Query query = em.createNativeQuery(queryString, Employee.class);
query.setParameter(1, "Mickey");
```

Please note that you **should not** use named parameters binding (`:empName`) in your query as JPA Spec says

> Only positional parameter binding may be portably used for native queries.

This should secure you from SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: I'd be grateful for an explanation why ? is better than :myParameter and how it prevents the injection.

Comment: Do you mean positional vs named paramaters binding? It was about native queries - JPA Specification does not guarantee portability in this case